# form_tag with same params as current rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I create a form_tag with the same current params but an additional param?

```
<%= form_tag(params.merge( :controller => "integrations", :action => "show" ), method: :get) do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :params, params[:q] %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-default"%>
 <% end %>
```

where my url looks like:

`http://localhost:3000/integrations/64?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bbio_or_topics_or_title_or_company_cont_any%5D=mcmaster&q%5Btitle_cont%5D=&q%5Bcompany_cont%5D=&q%5Blocation_cont_any%5D=&sort_by=twitter_followers&q%5Bfacebook_username_not_eq%5D=&q%5Btwitter_username_not_eq%5D=&q%5Blinkedin_username_not_eq%5D=&q%5Blocation_not_eq%5D=&commit=Search`

Thanks!